# произвольно меняется выравнивание текста кнопки при нажатии

Tags: android, button, scrollview

Помогите решить проблемку: делаю приложение, тестирую на своем телефоне.
на экране есть ScrollView внутри которого 3 TextView, ниже расположены несколько кнопок. При нажатии на одну из кнопок, в одном из TextView добавляется текст, в результате чего TextView увеличивается, и как только текст начинает "вылазить" за границы экрана, то есть появляется возможность прокрутки, также появляется "косяк", при нажатии на кнопку, текст расположенный в центре смещается к верхнему краю кнопки, как будто сменили gravity c CENTER на TOP. до этого текст на всех кнопках строго по центру, как только текст переполнил экран, нажатие на кнопку с текстом по центру меняет его положение, пока у всех кнопок, текст не окажется вверху, обратно "возвращается" только после перезапуска приложения, что это может быть? Что создает такой эффект и почему только в момент нажатия для одной кнопки, а не разом для всех кнопок, ну и как лечить?
Прошу прощения, если не понятно изложился.
Заранее благодарен всем откликнувшимся)) PS Яндекс гуглил ))

Comment: Используемая IDE не имеет отношения к проблеме в вопросе.